# Cannot connect to MS SQL 2008 R2 by DBVisualizer. "Native SSPI library not loaded" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to connect to MS SQL 2008R2 database by DBVisualizer.
I use jTDS driver, but following error occurs

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLException
   SQL State: 08S01
```

I added *ntlmauth.dll* to *jre/bin* but it didn't help.
I have java 1.6.0_25.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a really widely used tool for SQL Server database administrators.  For better answers, I'd contact DBVisualizer's support.

Comment: DBVisualizer has a very nice diagramming graph layout for showing table references.  IMHO better than SSMS at least for visualising

Comment: @BozoJoe nonetheless, it'd probably still be better for OP to contact DBVisualizer support.

Answer (score 2):

Download the jTDS driver from the following web site as it contain the needed files:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/

(Pick the jtds-1.2.5-src.zip file).

Unpack it and then read the README.SSO file.

In order for Single Sign On to work, jTDS must be able to load the native
    SPPI library (ntlmauth.dll). Place this DLL anywhere in the system path
    (defined by the PATH system variable) and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

If your using the [sqlJDBC4 driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) you have to jump through an extra hoop.

Once you have used the DBVisualizer "Driver Finder" you need to place the correct sqljdbc_auth.dll (x86 vs x64) in the jre/bin directory used by DBVisualizer.   In my case I use the 64 bit DBVisualizer with an embedded jre.  so my directory is:

```
C:\Program Files\DbVisualizer\jre\bin
```

which means I needed to copy from:

```
sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find **`dbvis.vmoptions`** in `c:\Program Files\DbVisualizer` and add following option there

**`-Djava.library.path="c:/ms_jdbc_41/sqljdbc_4.1/enu/auth/x64"`**

just after the line

**`-Dsun....`**

Answer (score 0):

Knowing by default newer SQL Server builds keep the TCP communications off whereas JDBC and jTDS require it I went ahead and enabled TCP in Configuration Tools -> Configuration Manager. In SQL Server Network Configurations -> Protocols I enabled the TCP protocol and then was able to connect.

[image: Image for reference]